# In Feistel cipher, is it possible to get LE0 from RE16 and RE0?

Tags: feistel-network

The notation I'm using here is from my textbook. I'm doing a CTF challenge where I need to know the value of $LE_0$. For now, I only have $RE_0$ and $RE_{16}$. I would like to know if it's possible to calculate $LE_0$ from just $RE_0$ and $RE_{16}$.

The round function F is splitmix64, which is used in generating pesudo random number and it has no subkey. In order to get $LE_0$, I first need to calculate $RD_0$ to plug in Feistel network again. It seems that it is possible to do it with only two rounds.
$$
    RE_0 ⊕ F(LE_0\ ⊕ F(RE_0))
$$
I can easily xor $RE_0$ with the formula above and apply the inverse function of $F$. This will yield $RD_0$. However, I can't see how it can be done with more than two rounds, because it always involve the unknown value $LE_0$. It makes me unable to calculate $RD_0$. Does anyone know how to do it?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography.SE. First of all, this is off-topic. Second, what is the round key size?. Third, what do you mean by no subkeys? Fifth, what is the book size?

Comment: Key size is 64bits in both $LE_0$ and $RE_0$. What I mean by no subkeys is that F is a hash function that does not need to feed in $K_1$ to $K_{16}$ in the figure.

Comment: what is the block size?

Comment: Block size is 128bits

Comment: Try some symbolic computation from the plaintext to see where it goes...